# Cracks from Garage Floor to the house

Tags: cracks

I closed on my home 5 months on 8/30/2018. Now I have noticed cracks on my garage floor. The cracks are getting wider. I am concerned. This is my first home. Please any advice?[image]

Comment: Also, the cracks are  leading from the garage to the house.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How wide is the crack? How old is the home? Is its foundation slab-on-grade?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of concrete, concrete that cracks and concrete that hasn't cracked yet. Houses are essentially floating on dirt and with proper preparation you can minimize the likelihood of a slab cracking. From the picture it does look like a large crack if it happened all of a sudden and is heaving it may cause an issue due being unlevel/trip hazard. But in general cracks in slabs are pretty common. Sidewalks don't crack often because of the expansion joints in between each section of sidewalk but that's impractical for a basement or garage slab. If it's a new build it may be cause for conren or if your house is an area subject to landslides or the sort, you may want to have someone investigate it.